# Licensing for Python ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I know that ANTLR4 is BSD license however what license does the python runtime for ANTLR 4.5 have?

There is no license file in the ANTLR 4 release package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent is BSD. I'll notify the author.